# Objective C const float * and Float tuple conversion to Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Last night I took a stab at porting over some code from ObjC to Swift and got to a point where I wasn't as familiar with what the Swift equivalent should be.

The main problem is how to represent a `const float *` in Swift. Based on the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23 I thought using `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` sounded like the acceptable conversion.

*ObjC*

```
- (void)renderWithModelViewProjectionMatrix:(const float *)model_view_matrix
```

*Swift*

```
func renderWithModelViewProjectionMatrix(modelViewMatrix: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>)
```

But when trying to pass in the `modelViewMatrix` argument I discovered that it was defined as a `Float` tuple `m` as shown below

```
public struct _GLKMatrix4 {

    public var m: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)
    public init(m: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float))
    public init()
}
```

Changing the method signature to

```
func renderWithModelViewProjectionMatrix(modelViewMatrix: (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float))
```

(although messy) seems to solve that initial problem.

The problem then becomes when trying to use that argument later on inside the method.

`glUniformMatrix4fv(cubeMVPMatrix, 1, 0, modelViewMatrix)`

resulting in the error `Cannot convert value of type (Float, Float, Float...) to expected argument type UnsafePointer<Float>`

Here is the `glUniformMatrix4fv` method signature for reference:

```
public func glUniformMatrix4fv(location: GLint, _ count: GLsizei, _ transpose: GLboolean, _ value: UnsafePointer<GLfloat>)
```

It seems that in ObjC the Float tuple can be represented as a `const float *` but in Swift it is not compatible with `UnsafePointer<Float>`.

What should  the `renderWithModelViewProjectionMatrix` method signature look like in Swift given the Float tuple being passed in? And how can it work with the call to `glUniformMatrix4fv` where it is expecting an UnsafeMutablePointer to be passed in?

Is there an easy conversion from `(Float, Float, Float...)` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`?

For a better understanding of the full source of ObjC I am converting from take a look at https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-ios/blob/master/CardboardSamples/TreasureHunt/TreasureHuntRenderer.m#L564

Comment: Why not just pass the _GLKMatrix4 directly?

Comment: It is the `m` value of the _GLKMatrix4 that is being passed in. Although possible to pass in the entire matrix, the problem then becomes how to you convert the `m` value from a Float tuple to an UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> expected as an argument to glUniformMatrix4fv. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tend to stick to obj-c/swift in iOS so I haven't really dealt with this personally, but if you're interfacing with c++ you might be better off sticking with Objective-C for now. My perception is it's more or less accidentally supported and they will likely do more work on it in later versions. see: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution -> out-of-scope

Comment: You could also do c++ -> Objective-C -> Swift to make things a bit easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though converting from the tuple to an array fixes the compile errors. Not sure how correct the solution is though.

```
typealias Matrix4Type = (Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float)

func arrayForTuple(tuple: Matrix4Type) -> [Float] {
    let reflection = Mirror(reflecting: tuple)
    var arr : [Float] = []
    reflection.children.forEach({ (label, value) in
        if let value = value as? Float {
            arr.append(value)
        }
    })
    return arr
}
```

and then inside `renderWithModelViewProjectionMatrix`

```
let modelViewMatrix = arrayForTuple(modelViewMatrixTuple)
glUniformMatrix4fv(cubeMVPMatrix, 1, 0, modelViewMatrix)
```